# Keep receiving "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and "float' . I know its probably a simple mistake but I cant find it

Tags: python

Keep getting the TypeError of an unsupported operand. I believe it to be when calling the active_met_rate but I'm not sure what needs to be corrected.

```
def bmr_calc():
  weightKg = int(input("Weight: "))
  heightInc = int(input("Height: "))
  age = int(input("Age: "))
  gender = input("Are you a (m)ale or (f)emale:").lower()

  if gender == "m":
    base_met_rate = int((66.47 + (6.24*weightKg) + (12.7*heightInc) - (6.76*age)))
  elif gender == "f":
    base_met_rate = int(((4.54*weightKg) + (15.88*heightInc) - (5*age) - 161))
  print("Your Basal Metabolic Rate is " + str(bas_met_rate) + " kcals")
  return base_met_rate

def amr_calc(base_met_rate):
  frequency = int(input("How many days do you work out?: "))
  if frequency == 0:
    act_fact = 1.2
  elif frequency == 1:
    act_fact = 1.2875
  elif frequency == 2:
    act_fact = 1.375
  elif frequency == 3:
    act_fact =1.41875
  elif frequency == 4:
    act_fact = 1.4625
  elif frequency == 5:
    act_fact = 1.55
  elif frequency == 6:
    act_fact = 1.6375
  elif frequency == 7:
    act_fact = 1.725
  active_met_rate = int(base_met_rate*act_fact)
  print("Your Active Metabolic Rate is " + str(active_met_rate) + " kcals")
  return(active_met_rate)

base_met_rate = bmr_calc
active_met_rate = amr_calc(base_met_rate)
```

Answer (score 2):

`bmr_calc` is a function that returns the Base Metabolic Rate. You need to call it, like this: `base_met_rate = bmr_calc()`. When you do that, then you can pass `base_met_rate`, which is a float, to `amr_calc`.

Comment: Thank you @2pichar. So simple but overlooked. Much appreciated